# How can i query firestore by field name and generate data in ionic 4 list using angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, observable, ionic4

I am using angular in IONIC 4 to get data from firestore, now am trying to get a list of `assignments` assigned to logged in `agent` by targeting a field called `agent_id` in `assignments` collection document.

I used firestore query to get data by still getting no data, I am getting size:0.

//  my assignments.service.ts

```ts
getByColumn(table: string, columnname: string, value: string) {
  return this.afs.collection<any>(table, ref =>
    ref.where(columnname, '==', value))
    .snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => {
        return actions.map(a => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data();
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;
          return { id, ...data };
        });
      })
    );
  }
```

// this is in my assignments.page.ts

```ts
export class AssignmentsPage implements OnInit {

  // assignments: any[];
  // assignments$: Observable<Assignments[]>;
  assignments: any[];
  agentid: any;
  agent: Agents;
  size: number;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router,
              private toastController: ToastController,
              private assignServises: DataService, 
              private data: AssignmentsService,
              private afs: AngularFirestore) {

    if (localStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn') === null) {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
    } else {
        this.agent = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('agent'));
        const id = localStorage.getItem('agent_id');
        this.agentid = this.agent.id;
        console.log('id:' + id + ' of ' + this.agent.lastname );

        // this.assignments = data.getAll();
        /* this.assignments$ = data.getAssignmentsByAgentId(id).
          pipe(
            tap(assignmentz => {
              if (assignmentz) {
                console.log('success: ' + assignmentz.length);
              } else {
                console.log('noo success: ' + assignmentz.length);
              }
            })); 
           */

        assignServises.getByColumn('assignments', 'agent_id', id)
          .subscribe(assgns => {
             this.assignments = assgns;
             this.size = assgns.length;
             console.log('assignmt: ' + assgns.map(assigmnt => assigmnt.status)); 
         });

  }
}
```

// this is my html page

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>{{agent.lastname}}'s My tasks</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
  <ion-badge>{{size}} assignment(s)</ion-badge>
    <ion-list *ngFor="let assignment of assignments$">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-card>
          <h3>Since: {{assignment.assigned_when}}</h3>
          <ion-label>Status: {{assignment.status}} </ion-label>
        </ion-card>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

the following shows how my data is structured in firebase
as you can see i have assignmnets and agents collection in each i have my own id to use to query each other as 1 agent can have one or many assignments assigned to him.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlY0z.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcIYv.png)

Comment: How is your data structured in the db? please show.

Comment: its structured as all main objects are structured as collections in firebase

Comment: i just added them images to show the structure of data

Comment: image 1 is here https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlY0z.png , image 2 is here https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcIYv.png

Comment: you are trying to query `assignments`, when your collection is named `Assignments`.

Comment: i changed the typo but still cant get the data. do u think my code is well written it should have got data from firestore? or in my code am missing something or doing something wrong. that my opinion. pls help

Answer (score 0):

First the issue is that you are trying to query `assignments` table, though the table is named `Assignments` with capital `A`. Second issue seems to be a type mismatch. In your image of your db, you have the `agent_id` as type `number`, whereas you are trying to query your table with a `string`. This matters. I assume you are always having an id in localStorage that can be a number, if so simply add a `+` in front of your id, which turns the string to number:

```ts
assignServises.getByColumn('Assignments', 'agent_id', +id)
```

and of course change the corresponding function parameter type to `number`:

```ts
getByColumn(table: string, columnname: string, value: number) {
```

Now your query should work as it should, given the `agent_id` exist in your document(s).